# When to use subclasses vs. when to use @classmethods in Python?

Tags: python, architecture

I believe the title may be a little confusing so I'll try to explain myself with exactly what I'm developing.

I have a script that runs over some data periodically, and checks if there are some anomalies, and sends me an email if it finds any.

Anomalies can be of several kinds, so I want the script to customize the email based on the kind of anomaly it finds.

Thus I created an Anomaly class, and several subclasses based on the type of anomalies I'm looking for, like this:

```py
class Anomaly(object):
    """Base class constructor."""

    def _send_email(self):
        [..]

    def _custom_message(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def anomaly(cls):
        cls._send_email(cls)


class Foo(Anomaly):

    def _custom_message(self):
        return "OMG! Foo Anomaly detected"


class Bar(Anomaly):

    def _custom_message(self):
        return "OMG! Bar Anomaly detected"
```

Then in my main script I have two different checks, calling `Foo.anomaly()` or `Bar.anomaly()` respectively.

However, I've read that it's also possible to do this all within a single class, using class method, something like:

```py
class Anomaly(object):

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return "OMG! Foo anomaly detected"
etc...
```

and then just call `Anomaly.foo()` / `Anomaly.bar()`.

So I'm wondering, which is the proper / most pythonic way to handle this? The way I wrote it already works, so it's more a matter of best practices in terms of software development.

Comment: Your subclasses make very little sense to me, why not provide the `custom_message` as an argument to the constructor of `Anomaly`? What do you gain by using inheritance? If the answer to that question isn't obvious, you should probably just use composition. You don't need a `@classmethod` either, you never actually use the class object in the classmethod...

Comment: Note, your entire class structure makes little sense. you've defined `def _send_email(self):` as an instance method, but call it through your classmethod: `cls._send_email(cls)` passing the class as the first argument, which is very inconsistent. Fundamentally, your design seems very confused, unless there is something missing here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No there isn't much missing, I am just quite new to software development in general and therefore I lack a lot of experience.

To answer your first question however, it's because the actual custom message is relatively long and fetches some environment variables, so I thought it was cleaner to keep it separated from the main script.

Comment: So, it seems to me like you are over-complicating things. Try to keep things as simple as possible. again, why not just a single anomaly class: `class Anomaly` with `def __init__(self, message)` which you rpovide the message on instantiation: `a = Anomaly("OMG! Foo anomaly detected")` with `def _custom_message(self): return self.message`. My answer to your question is that you should use neither inheritance nor a classmethod in this case, at least, why you've shown provides no motivation for using either.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh, and regarding the ```@classmethod```, I thought I needed it because I didn't want to create a class instance such as ```a = Anomaly()```, instead I wanted to be able to call the ```anomaly()``` method from the class itself, and I had read that ```@classmethods``` allow you to do just that.

Essentially in the main script it would be: ```if error_detected: Foo.anomaly()```

Comment: But why? If you don't want to create an instance, you probably don't need a class at all. `@classmethod` is used more frequently to provide alternative constructors. Sometimes, also, you need to modify the state of the class and @classmethod provides a good way to do that. But would you simply not be creating an instance at all? Then you probably don't need a class at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok I understood. I agree this is probably overcomplicating it, I guess I should read up more and understand better ```@classmethods``` and inheritance principles

Comment: In general, you should prefer composition over inheritance, and when you use inheritance, try to keep hierarchies shallow. Python also provides multiple inheritance, and there are various ways to use that, but again, don't go crazy. One pretty useful pattern is the mixin pattern, but again, for your own code, start simple.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah, I guess self teaching myself is leaving some knowledge holes here and there. Thanks for the headsup!